# It is possible to set the default schema used by phinx, in php, to create the default_migration_table?

Tags: php, database-migration, phinx

I'm using [phinx](http://phinx.org/) in my project and i'm trying to change the schema of  `default_migration_table`, something like this:

```
environments:
    default_migration_table: mySchema.phinxlog #default schema is public
    default_database: development
...
```

But it fails:

```
[PDOException]                                                                             
  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "mySchema.phinxlog" does not exist  
  LINE 1: SELECT * FROM mySchema.phinxlog ORDER BY version ASC                             
                        ^
```

If i create the `phinxlog` table in `mySchema` it works fine, but it would be desirable that the phinx auto create the table in my schema.
Is there some setting to make it do this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove "mySchema." from mysSchema.phinxlog - it should just be phinxlog (or whatever you want to call it).

Comment: My question is about the schema used to create the `phinxlog` table. If i remove the "`mySchema`" the table will be created in the default schema (`public`), as i don't want. So this is not a valid answer.  I need to specify the schema!